# getNodeValue() giving me null, while getNodeName() giving me #text

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, dom-traversal

if i have a XML file like this

```
<UI>
<Option type="menu">
    <Name>MENU1</Name>
    <Option type="action">
        <Name>Action1</Name>
        <Function>Clicked Action1</Function>
    </Option>
</Option>
</UI>
```

to fetch the value of first text node(MENU1)  i m doing the following:

```
Node rootNode=dom1.getFirstChild();
String name=rootNode.getNodeValue();
Log.i(TAG,"ROOT NAME is :=",name);
```

the above code is giving me blank space, while by using

```
 Sting name=rootNode.getNodeName();
```

it is giving me #text, that means it does have a text but why is it not showing??

Answer (score 0):

add one extra node above of option

```
<test> 
<Option type="menu">
  <Name>MENU1</Name>
  <Option type="action">
      <Name>Action1</Name>
      <Function>Clicked Action1</Function>
  </Option>
</Option>
</test>
```

and check the following url you will be able to get values of all nodes
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/sax/get-element-attributes-in-sax-xml-parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try the Document Object Model (DOM parser)

**See this snippet of code:**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory odbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder odb =  odbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            Document odoc = odb.parse(is);
            odoc.getDocumentElement().normalize ();    // normalize text representation
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + odoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList LOP = odoc.getElementsByTagName("locations");
            int totalPersons =LOP.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total nos of locations:"+totalPersons);

            for(int s=0; s<LOP.getLength() ; s++)
            {
                Node FPN =LOP.item(s);
                if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {

                    Element latlon = (Element)FPN;                                                                

                    NodeList oNameList1 = latlon.getElementsByTagName("featured");                                       
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element)oNameList1.item(0);
                    NodeList textNList1 = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    //this.setLocationId(((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());                                 
                    System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");
                    System.out.println("featured : " + ((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());            
                    System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");

                   }



       }
```

**For more details see this link:**

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Comment: getting node value via NodeList is not a problem, the problem is i have to do a depth first traversal in the DOM tree to reach each and every node and then fetch values. Thats what my code requires.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem. Please try out **getTextContent()** menthod rather than getNodeValue().